# Automatically capitalize all input in WPF

Tags: wpf, input, uppercase

Is there a way to automatically capitalize all input throughout a WPF app?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can case all input into `TextBox` controls with the following property:

```
CharacterCasing="Upper"
```

To apply to all `TextBox` controls in the entire application create a style for all `TextBox` controls:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="CharacterCasing" Value="Upper"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: I know this doesn't solve ALL input casing, but most text input would come in through TextBox controls.

Comment: I believe it's "TargetType" instead of "DataType":

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"> 
    <Setter Property="CharacterCasing" Value="Upper"/> 
</Style>

Comment: @Wes: Good catch. DataType is used for DataTemplates. Updated.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to capitalize the input for a single `TextBox` rather than all `TextBox`es like [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/836197/2597913), you can use the following:

```
<TextBox CharacterCasing="Upper"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a custom Textbox class and override an event to automatically capitalize the text.  First, this depends on if you want the text to be capitalize as they type or after input is finished.

E.g. for after input is finished

```
public class AutoCapizalizeTextBox: TextBox
{
  public AutoCapitalizeTextBox()
  {
  }

  public AutoCapitlizeTextBox()
  {
  }

  protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
  {
    this.Text = this.Text.ToUpper();

    base.OnLostFocus(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this'll help, it capitalizes all the first letters in the sentence.

http://www.mardymonkey.co.uk/blog/auto-capitalise-a-text-control-in-wpf/

Comment: The link is broken.  https://web.archive.org/web/20170210180855/http://www.mardymonkey.co.uk/blog/auto-capitalise-a-text-control-in-wpf/ is the archive of it.

Comment: This solution just uses a pre-built DLL and doesn't show how to write the code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a converter.
Here's the code of the converter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
namespace SistemaContable.GUI.WPF.Converters
{
    public class CapitalizeFirstLetter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                string stringToTitleCase = culture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(value.ToString());
                return stringToTitleCase;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to reference it in a "ResourceDictionary" or in your "App.xaml":

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:SistemaContable.GUI.WPF.Converters">
    <converters:CapitalizeFirstLetter x:Key="CapitalizeFirstLetter"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And you can use it like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtNombre" Text="{Binding Usuario.Nombre, Converter={StaticResource CapitalizeFirstLetter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```